# Зачем нужен @ResponseBody?

Tags: java, spring

Зачем использовать в рест-контроллере @ResponseBody в ответе, если можно обойтись без него?
Например

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/status", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String update(){
    return "hello";
}
```

возвращают одинаковый результат:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/status", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(){
    return "hello";
}
```

Comment: Нет смысла, потому что Restcontroller автоматически добавляет ResponseBody к ответу. Можете в жава доке аннотации посмотреть.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В случае со String разницы действительно нет (в вашем случае), потому что строка превращается в тело HTTP-ответа довольно очевидным образом.

Однако, в Spring MVC методы контроллера могут возвращать не только String, а [много других интересных вещей](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-return-types). Аннотация `@ResponseBody` дает фреймворку понять, что объект, который вы вернули из метода надо прогнать через [`HttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html), чтобы получить готовое к отправке на клиент представление.

PS. Кстати, обратите внимание, что аннотация относится не к объявлению типа возращаемого значения, а к объявлению метода целиком. Поэтому можно писать и так:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/status", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String update(){
    return "hello";
}
```